# How do you retrieve current date for Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm a newbie in Symfony 2 and i would like to know how do i get current date(today's date) from symfony2 and display in my twig.

Any kind souls willing to help?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 98, accepted):

In twig

```
{{ 'now'|date('d - m -Y') }}
```