# How can I add current month & year as a placeholder text in twig file?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

{{ form_widget(form.monthYear,{'attr':{'placeholder': 'e.g. mm-YYYY'}} }}

How can I do this **mm-YYYY** to **04-2021**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the [`date`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/date.html) filter? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18394736/4205384) might help, you just need to adjust the format to what you want.

Comment: I tried that. It does not work for placeholder value @El_Vanja

Comment: Dont place it inside quotes go with `{ 'placeholder' : 'NOW'|date('m-Y'), }`

Comment: Thanks. @DarkBee. It worked. How to concatenate `e.g.` with that?

Comment: `'eg'~'NOW'|date`

Comment: Thanks again. @DarkBee. Problem is solved! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
{{ form_widget(form.monthYear, {
    'attr': {
        'placeholder': "now"|date("m-Y")
    }
}}
```